# Python: References between subclasses

Tags: python, oop, overriding

Say I have a set of classes like these:

```
class User(object):

    def __init__(self, profile):
        # ...
        pass

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls):
        profile = Profile()
        user = cls(profile)

class Profile(object):
    pass

class SpecialUser(User):
    pass

class SpecialProfile(Profile):
    pass
```

Whenever I want to subclass `User` or `Profile`, I need to sort of subclass all of them, because with the code above, if I do `SpecialUser.create_user()` it will be a special user, but with a regular profile.

The simplest workaround is to make an overridable factory function inside `User`, that creates the appropriate `Profile`. However, this can be kind of tedious. What if a User had a Profile and like 10 other classes? Would I have to override a factory function for each of these? What if the other classes also referenced each other? Would all those classes need factory functions too?

I've thought about doing something like this:

```
class UserClasses(object):

    class User(object):

        def __init__(self, profile):
            # ...
            pass

        @classmethod
        def create_user(cls):
            profile = cls.__parent__.Profile()
            user = cls(profile)

    class Profile(object):
        pass

class SpecialUserClasses(UserClasses):

    class Profile(UserClasses.Profile):
        pass
```

Wrapping all of these classes inside another class means that if I subclass the outer class and override one of the inner classes, any other inner classes that references that class will automatically use the overridden one. Problem is, the `__parent__` syntax does not exist, and based on my searches there isn't an easy way for inner classes to get their outer class.

**How can I get `classmethod`-like functionality, but for groups of related classes?**

Comment: Do you really need to be able to handle "10 other classes that also reference each other"?  If there can be an arbitrary web of references between all these classes I don't see how you could ever handle it without it being confusing and laborious.

Comment: This sounds like [ACL's](http://www.limscoder.com/2009/11/role-based-security-with-python.html) Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @BrenBarn, in my specific case these classes will be [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) models with relationships to each other (and actually abstract ones at that), so they will need to have information like "User has Profile," "Comment has User" etc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to use an overridable function.  You could just have an overridable attribute:

```
class User(object):

    profile_class = Profile

    def __init__(self, profile):
        # ...
        pass

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls):
        profile = cls.profile_class()
        user = cls(profile)
```

Then subclasses can just define their own `profile_class` attribute and it will work.  To do this, though, any user class must be defined *after* its corresponding profile class (since the user class references the profile class in the class body).  This limits the complexity of the cross-referencing you can have.  In reality, however, a complex system of mutually referential classes is often confusing and fragile.

Comment: Would there be a convenient way to put the profile_class, other_class, someother_class into a "factory class" and have each class have a reference to just that class? I'm thinking by using decorators to set each class as an attribute on it.

Comment: @awesome: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  What is "just that class"?